# How does the for loops function here?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

What does the following code do?

I am confused on how the for loops function here, and would appreciate any help to understand.

```
average_mae_history = [np.mean([x[i] for x in all_mae_histories]) for i in range(num_epochs)]
```

Suppose a`vg_mae_history` has say 4 lists each with 500 elements, where the 4 lists correspond to the 4 folds and 500 elements correspond to the 500 epochs performed for each fold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking questions without trying out and telling what you have done in order to clarify your doubt is wrong.
Anyway I will explain the code snippet:
Its a simple list comprehension with two for loops.
What it basically does is:

```
for i in range(num_epochs):
    for j in all_mae_history:
        temp = []
        temp.append(j[i])
    z.append(max(temp))
```

Next time tell us what you have done before posting code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, So it finds the average value of mae for every epoch from the k folds ie average value of ith epoch out of the 500 epochs for the kth fold out of 4 folds so that we get a list with 500 avg. mae?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be

```
mean = [np.mean([x[i] for x in all_mae_histories]) for i in range(num_epochs)]
print('mean - ', mean)
z = []
for i in range(num_epochs):
    temp = []
    for j in all_mae_histories:
        temp.append(j[i])
    z.append(np.mean(temp))
print('mean z ', z)
```